# Does checking against null for 'success' count as "Double use of variables"?

Tags: c#

I have read that a variable should never do more than one thing.  Overloading a variable to do more than one thing is bad.

Because of that I end up writing code like this:  (With the `customerFound` variable)

```
bool customerFound = false;
Customer foundCustomer = null;
if (currentCustomer.IsLoaded)
{
    if (customerIDToFind = currentCustomer.ID)
    {
        foundCustomer = currentCustomer;
        customerFound = true;
    }
}
else
{
    foreach (Customer customer in allCustomers)
    {
        if (customerIDToFind = customer.ID)
        {
            foundCustomer = customer;
            customerFound = true;
        }
    }
}
if (customerFound)
{
    // Do something
}
```

But deep down inside, I sometimes want to write my code like this: (Without the `customerFound` variable)

```
Customer foundCustomer = null;
if (currentCustomer.IsLoaded)
{
    if (customerIDToFind = currentCustomer.ID)
    {
        foundCustomer = currentCustomer;
    }
}
else
{
    foreach (Customer customer in allCustomers)
    {
        if (customerIDToFind = customer.ID)
        {
            foundCustomer = customer;
        }
    }
}
if (foundCustomer != null)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Does this secret desires make me an evil programmer?

(i.e. is the second case really bad coding practice?)

Comment: The second snippet is fine, except you could replace the foreach with a LINQ expression just to make things tidier. There is clearly a hole where if you enter the first path *and* the customerIDToFind value doesn't equal currentCustomer.ID, you'll not set the foundCustomer, but I assume that's part of your logical design.

Comment: No more evil than BitVector32. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx

Comment: +1 for questioning conventional wisdom, even though your understanding of conventional wisdom was wrong ;)

Comment: No, thats fine, except you are assigning in your "if" statements.  make it == instead of = and you're golden

Comment: Please, add a `break` after you've found what you're looking for, unless you intend to search your entire set and return the last. Assuming customer ID is unique, you're always iterating the entire set, which is wasteful, when you can terminate as soon as you've found the item you're looking for.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the advice. In that case, you're only using the variable for one purpose - to store the customer being searched for. Your logic checks to see if the customer was found, but doesn't change the purpose of the variable.

The "don't use variables for more than one thing" is aimed at things like "temp" variables that store state for ten different things during the course of a function.

Comment: ++ Where this is a problem is in assembly language, where registers get used as variables and their meaning can change. It is also a typical issue in Fortran where, for example, a subroutine to take the square root of a matrix might overwrite the original, forcing you to use one matrix variable for two meanings, depending on location. Boy, that's annoying.

Answer (score 10):

You're asking about and demonstrating 2 different things.

1. **What you're asking about:** Using the same variable for 2 different things.  For example storing a user's age and also his height with a single double variable.
2. **What you're demonstrating:** Using 2 variables for the same purpose.

I like your second code variant better, you have 1 variable not 2 that are co-dependent.  The first piece of code may have more problems as you have more state to manage to signify the same exact thing.

I think the root thing that you're asking about is: Is it ok to use a magic value instead of a separate variable?  It depends on your situation, but if you are guaranteed that the magic value (null in this case) can't be used otherwise to signify anything else, then go ahead.

---

**When you would use the first variant of code that you gave:**

If you can have a null value even if an object is found, and you need to distinguish that between actually finding a customer or not, then you should use the 2 variable variant.

Comment: Isn't it same as `TryParse` method in .net for `int32`? i.e `bool parsed = int.TryParse("32", out integerValue);`. why do you think it is wrong to have co-dependent variable as long as it is used in a limited scope? link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Comment: @shahkalpesh: No it's not the same, in that case the bool is meant to show an invalid parsing exception.  You can't rely on a magic number but if it returned int? then it would be comparable.  And it's also dissimilar at other levels.

Comment: @shahkalpesh: See the last paragraph in my edit where I explain why you would want to do something like TryParse.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand that this example doesn't relate directly with `TryParse`. However, whats wrong with 2 variables example? I couldn't agree with the justification in case of "If you can have a null value even if an object is found, and you need to distinguish that between actually finding a customer or not, then you should use the 2 variable variant."

Comment: @shahkalpesh: I'm not against 2 variables, I'm against using 2 variables for the exact same purpose.  Redundant information means you have to maintain redundant information that's all.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I'd consider refactoring this into methods to find and check your customer, thereby reducing this block length dramatically.  Something like:

```
Customer foundCustomer = null;
if (!this.TryGetLoadedCustomer(out foundCustomer))
    foundCustomer = this.FindCustomer();

if (foundCustomer != null)
{ // ...
```

That being said, you're using the `foundCustomer` variable for a single purpose here, in both cases.  It's being used in multiple places, but it's used for a single purpose - to track the correct customer.

If you're going to use the code as you have it above, I personally prefer the second case over your first option - since a null check is probably going to be required in any case.

Comment: +1, I think refactoring the job of finding customers and calling that procedure once is probably the best way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 5):

The second way is better in my opinion as well. I'd say the first way is actually wrong, as you have two variables that depend on each other and give you redundant information. This opens the possibility of them being inconsistent - you can make a mistake and have `customerFound` be `true`, but `foundCustomer` be `null`. What do you in that case? It's better for that state to be impossible to reach.

Comment: Exactly right. A pretty good measure of how well written a piece of code is is how many invalid states it allows. In this case by eliminating the boolean we eliminate half the invalid states with no loss of functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the second case is better than the first.  Checking a variable against NULL does not constitute an entire other usage in my book.  The second case is better because you have copied code in the first where you have to set the flag and set the variable.  This is error prone if you had another case where you set the Customer but then forgot to set the flag.

Answer (score 2):

In the second piece of code, a null value of foundCustomer indicates that no customer was found. This sounds perfectly reasonable, and I would not consider that to be a double use of the variable at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you make it your mission to create **simple code** that other developers can understand easily, if you make that your beacon instead of a set of rigid rules from 1985, you will find your way.

There are a lot of practices that come from old school procedural development, where routines were more likely to be monolithic and extremely long. We can still learn from them, don't get me wrong, but we have many new strategies for handling complexity and creating human readable/self describing code, so to me the idea that this should be a hard and fast rule seems obsolescent at best.

That said, I would probably refactor this code into a two or three smaller methods, and then the variable reuse question would probably go away. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the second option makes pretty good sense. Why waste a variable if you can live without it?

But in the foreach statement I would add a break if the customer is found.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue the opposite.  You're actually adding additional lines of code to achieve the same result which makes your first code example more prone to errors and harder to maintain.

I agree with the consensus, you're doing fine checking for nulls, the advice is really warning against something horrid like:

```
float x;
x=37;     // current age

if (x<50) {
    x=x/10;    // current height
    if (x>3) {
        x=3.14;    // pi to the desired level of precision
    }
}

if (x==3.14) {
   // hooray pi for everyone old enough
}
else {
    // no pi for you youngster!
}
```

btw, I know it's just a wee code snippet, but I can't help but think that there is something wrong with:

```
if (customerIDToFind = currentCustomer.ID)
{
    foundCustomer = currentCustomer;
}
else {
    // foundCustomer remains null
}

if (!foundCustomer) {
    // always true when currentCustomer.IsLoaded 
}
```

That would mean that once you have a loaded customer then you'll never again search for another one.  I'm guessing that you pruned a bit of handy code to make an example, if that's the case then please ignore this part of the comment! ;-)

Comment: I did change up the code quite a bit for this example.  No sense in boring everyone with the full code listing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the second version, but I'm not sure if your sample was very good because I don't think that it is doing two things. Checking a variable for null is standard practice.